# Get Facebook name from id with API/crawler

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-crawler

I am trying to get Facebook name of user according to his Facebook id.
for example if my Facebook is: Mor Amit
and my Facebook id is: 875810135770071
i want to get the name of the Facebook that is: mor.amit.3
Do you know how can i do it?
Thank you
*I am using java

Comment: That is the username and that is not available in the API. So no that is not possible

Comment: Actually its possible and you don't have to use the FB API you can parse the DOM of the user page to retrieve the basic information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't mentioned which language you are using I'll use PHP since its easier and quicker to learn (my opinion).

If you have the ID then this link will take you the user profile:

`www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=<user id digits only>`

If you have the username then you can use:

`www.facebook.com/<user name>`

Once you loaded the page lets say using PHP ([curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)) you can find inside the content (DOM) using [regex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) - dirty parsing:

- FB **user id** regex pattern: `/data-profileid="([0-9]{0,})"/i`
- FB user **real name** regex pattern: `/fb-timeline-cover-name">(.{0,})<\/span>/i`
- FB **user name** regex pattern: `/URL=\/(.{0,})\?{1}/i`

Its better to parse the content (you can use - [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)) and then traverse the DOM but that's more complex.

Have fun exploring and learning.